# Get the names of all the tables and the views in a single SQL query for SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` gives the table names and `sys.views` gives the view names. But I'm not able to get both in a single query result. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is there are reason you can not use a UNION to combine two select statements into one query?

Comment: What's the needs of `UNION` while he can get all the information from `sys.objects` @TomTom

Comment: Using information schema. And asking around the question that is trivially solvable with making 2 select combined in a union, which he says he knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.views`([sys.views (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) doesn't give you the list of column names, it (unsurprisingly) gives you the list `VIEW` objects in the database:

> Contains a row for each view object, with sys.objects.type = V.

You either want the (appropriately named) `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` or perform a `JOIN` from `sys.tables` to `sys.columns` on `object_id`.

---

That one word you changed completely changes the question. Instead you now want `sys.objects`:

```
SELECT [name]
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE [type] IN ('U','V');
```

`'U'` means User Table, and `'V'` means View.

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake. I actually want the table and view names so I think that the join might not be helpful.

Comment: Yes, and that one word completely changes your question, @SrivatsaBalaji . I have added more to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` is incorrect.  It has both tables and views -- despite the name.

If you want one or the other type, then check `TABLE_TYPE` which can be either `'VIEW'` or `'BASE_TABLE'`.

So this does what you want:

```
select t.*
from information_schema.tables t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this SQL:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG='dbName'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below system procedure will get all tables and views names. [Read more on sp_tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

`sp_tables`

You can also filter the list using wildcharacters.

`sp_tables 'tablename%'`

**Additional Info:** There is a corresponding procedure for stored procedures list
`sp_stored_procedures`